# How much ice will reduce the chicken carcass temperature from 32 to 8 degree C

Tags: thermodynamics

I am interested to learn through heat claculations the quantity of ice that would achieve a chicken carcass core temperature of 8 degree C.

My chilling tank has a volume of 15,000 liters of flowing water where chicken pass through at a rate of 3,000 carcass per hour having an average carcass weight of 1.4kg and deep muscle temperature of 32 degree C.The flowing water drains at a rate of 5 litres per second.

Supplementary ice added to the chilled water at 250kg per hour while 8 degree C chilled water is fed into the tank at 4800 liters per hour.

How much more ice is required per hour to reduce the core temperature of chicken to 8 degree C? Appreciate a detailed calculation.

I thank you for your time and efforts.